# Can't raise nginx max files opened limit

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ulimit

I'm running Ubuntu Server. This is what I've done:

*/etc/security/limits.conf:*

```
*               soft    nofile          10240
*               hard    nofile          10240
```

*And added in /etc/pam.d/common-session:*

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

*And nginx conf itself /etc/nginx/nginx.conf*

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1; #I have only 1 core
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 10240;
    # multi_accept on;
}

worker_rlimit_nofile 10240;
```

*But trying to confirm changes:*

```
root@ubuntu_ngix:~# ulimit -Hn
4096
root@ubuntu_ngix:~# ulimit -Sn
1024
```

I have restart nginx and also my server, but still nothing. What am I doing wrong here?

I'm running nginx as www-data user.

Comment: What version of ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 1):

The config `/etc/security/limits.conf` is specific to [PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module). *PAM*, in general, is not used by software that *manages services* such as *nginx*.

So everything from [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init), to [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/), to [systemd](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) do not use the `limits.conf` at all.

`nginx` has a specific configuration setting for increasing the file descriptor limit [worker_rlimit_nofile](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_rlimit_nofile).

Outside of all configuration blocks (not in `http` or a `server`) add:

```
worker_rlimit_nofile 10240
```

Comment: This won't set it for the master process. It will only work for worker processes.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of `/etc/security/limits.conf`.  It should be world readable (mode 0644).

I've spent many moons trying to figure out why limits won't take effect before.