# Nginx at startup does not have fd limit set in /etc/security/limits.conf

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, init.d, ulimit

I have the following configuration for increasing the number of file descriptors available to processes of all users.

```
cat /etc/security/limits.conf

* hard nofile 65536
* soft nofile 65536
```

When the machine starts up, nginx is set to start as a service under the nginx user, and if I check the limits under /proc//limits it is 1024/4096

```
Max open files            1024                4096                files
```

Without changing any settings or configuration files, if I then restart the nginx service with a `sudo service nginx restart`

The limits go up to 65536/65536

```
Max open files            65536                65536                files
```

Anyway to make sure it starts up the first time with those limits?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/721807/168178