# How do I increase open file limit for nginx's master process on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, upstart, init.d

**Not a dupe:** This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/721752/cant-raise-nginx-max-files-opened-limit). I've already looked into that question. That helps with raising the limit for `worker processes`, but the nginx `master process` continues to retain `1024` and `4096` respectively. This latter nuance is what this question is really about.

---

**The problem:**

I'm increasing file descriptor limit for nginx in `systemd` as follows:

1) Create `limit.conf` in `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/`

2) Save the following lines in this file

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=100000
```

3) Restart nginx via `sudo service nginx restart`

Now when I do `cat /proc/$(ps aux | grep "nginx: master process" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')/limits | grep "Max open files"` I can see this limit set up correctly.

However there is a catch!

If I reboot the system and then re-enter it, the default for nginx's `master process` is back to `1024` and `4096` (I run the aforementioned `cat` command to find out).

But if I issue `sudo service nginx start`, the limit increases again as desired.

**How do I ensure this setting is not lost on reboots?** Would appreciate an illustrative example. I don't want to manually have to issue `sudo service nginx restart` each time.

---

p.s. I've made complementary changes in `/etc/security/limits.conf` and `/etc/pam.d/common-session` as well. Ask me for more information in case you need it.

Moreover, `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nginx.service` contains:

```
[Unit]
Description=nginx - high performance web server
Documentation=http://nginx.org/en/docs/
After=network-online.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/nginx.pid
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But it's `14.04`, so that wouldn't have worked any way. What's the best way to accomplish this on Ubuntu 14.04? Would love an illustrative example that actually works.

Comment: Then trying to configure systemd really won't work, because there is no systemd. 14.04 will be end of life in a few weeks anyway. You may as well upgrade.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Fair enough. I'm trying that in a separate virtual machine now, let's see if I get through without boot errors by the end of it. As for the scope of this question, if I were to set `LimitNOFILE=100000` in a 14.04 environment, how would you propose I do it?

Comment: I honestly don't even remember. It's been a very long time since I had any Linux systems that didn't use systemd.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't raise nginx max files opened limit](https://serverfault.com/questions/721752/cant-raise-nginx-max-files-opened-limit)

Comment: @Thomas: Already looked into that. That helps with raising the limit for `worker processes`, but the nginx master process continues to retain `1024` and `4096` respectively.